# Последовательный запуск всех проектов

Tags: c#

У меня есть 5 проектов в Visual Studio. Как программно запустить их по очереди с отрывками в 3 секунды, т.е. запустился первый проект, через 3 секунды - второй и т.д.

Comment: Без паузы в 3 секунды - список запускаемых проектов настраивается в свойствах решения.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить решение без паузы:

В `Solution Explorer` нажмите правой кнопкой мыши на ваш солюшен и выберите и выберите в меню `Properites`. В открывшемся меню => `Common Properties` => выберите `Multuiple startup projects`. Дальше в столбце `Action` выберите: start\start with debuging.

Comment: Как добавить проекты, что-то не вижу кнопки

Comment: Я только один проект вижу в списке

Comment: А мне надо все 5 штук

Comment: Проекты должны быть в одном солюшене

Comment: Если хотите добавить проект, то пкм по солюшену->добавить проект

Comment: как через софт в указанной папке, во всех подпапках переименовать все exe как названии папки то есть есть папка test а exe teesssttttt то переименовать exe согласно названию папки, не могу, система не дает задать новый

Comment: @May_be если у вас есть вопрос который не касается темы данного топика, то заведите отдельный вопрос.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35172/discussion-between-may-be-and--).